# Having trouble understanding the intuition behind the Arithmetic series formula

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

Im having trouble understanding the intuition behind adding the average together "n" times. For example if we had a a sequence of 1-9 and we wanted to find the series. I understand the average of 1&9 is 5 and its the same for all the terms. I dont understand how adding this average gives the sum.

Comment: Observe that $1+2+3+4 = (1+4)+(2+3)=(1+4)/2+(1+4)/2+(2+3)/2+(2+3)/2=4(5/2)=10$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rl}&(1&+2&+3&+4&+5&+6&+7&+8&+9)\\+&(9&+8&+7&+6&+5&+4&+3&+2&+1)\\\hline &10&+10&+10&+10&+10&+10&+10&+10&+10\end{array}$$

Calling the number $S$ the total of $1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9$ the above implies that $S+S=9\cdot 10$.  In other words $2S=90$.  Dividing by two gives $S=\frac{90}{2}=45$

More generally, we can prove by induction that $1+2+3+4+\dots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

This is essentially the same observation and argument made in this proof without words from [the art of problemsolving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Proofs_without_words):

[image]

Comment: love the geometric/algebraic connections here.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose we have an arithmetic series starting at $1$ and moving $1$ step at a time. In other words, let's consider the series $1,2,3........, (n-2),(n-1),n$.

Let's now look at the sums: $$n + 1$$ $$n-1 +2 = n+1$$ $$n-2 + 3= n+1$$ $$...$$ and so on.

Since this repeats $\frac{n}{2}$ times, then the sum of the series is the same as the product $$(n+1)\frac{n}{2}$$

Example: 
let's consider the series $1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$. 
It is obvious that$$1+10=11$$ $$2+9=11$$ $$3+8=11$$ $$4+7=11$$ and $$5+6=11$$

and so the sum $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 5*11 = 55$

Note that if you substitute for $n=10$ in the formula $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, you'd get: $$\frac{10(10+1)}{2} = 5*11 =55$$.

Generally, if you have an arithmetic series with first term $a$ and common difference $d$, the sum of the first $n$ terms is: $$\frac{n[2a +(n-1)d]}{2}$$

Comment: thank you, this way of thinking really clicked for me

Comment: "*since this repeats $\frac{n}{2}$ times*", careful, $\frac{n}{2}$ is not an integer in the case that $n$ is odd.

Comment: this is right, but in this particular case, it doesn't really matter as the product $n(n+1)$ is always divisible by 2.